# Object from select list options values

Tags: javascript, jquery

Want to make an object containing all select list options values and their inner text. Problem is that instead of making one object with all option values in it, when console log seems like gettin' thee different objects.

[Here goes my code][1]

```js
let values = {};
$('select option').each(function() {
    var optionValue = $(this).attr('value');
    var optionText = $(this).text();
    console.log(optionValue, optionText);
  Object.assign(values, {optionValue: optionText});
    console.log(values);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
    <option value="one">Value one</option>
    <option value="two">Value two</option>
    <option value="three">Value three</option>
</select>
```

Where I'm wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is creating an object with `optionValue` as key and it's being overwritten every time. If your intention is to create an object with the value of `optionValue` as key, then use the [computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names). You need to wrap the `optionValue` with `[]` to use a variable as a key:

```js
let values = {};

$('select option').each(function() {
  var optionValue = $(this).attr('value');
  var optionText = $(this).text();

  Object.assign(values, {
    [optionValue]: optionText
  });

});

console.log(values);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select>
  <option value="one">Value one</option>
  <option value="two">Value two</option>
  <option value="three">Value three</option>
</select>
```